# Invalid grant while accessing PowerBi api

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I an using PowerBI report on my project by creating azure application on my tenant.
The report smoothly renders in my local environment but when I publish my app to azure the PowerBI report will not display and gives this error.

> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user or
>   administrator has not consented to use the application with ID
>   '55a3b089-c45c-4496-b2db-63c98f6b3543'. Send an interactive
>   authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID:
>   4c886bc7-2693-455b-9911-ed7cbe9daca6\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   a36225e3-5c41-47f6-981b-be21de839d1b\r\nTimestamp: 2017-02-22
>   10:37:15Z","error_codes":[65001],"timestamp":"2017-02-22
>   10:37:15Z","trace_id":"4c886bc7-2693-455b-9911-ed7cbe9daca6","correlation_id":"a36225e3-5c41-47f6-981b-be21de839d1b"}

What configuration have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error info it indicates that the authorization is invalid. But you mentioned it works correctly in local environment. So It is very odd. I can't repro it with [demo code](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/tree/master/samples/webforms/get-started-web-app-asp.net). It also works  correctly in the Azure environment.The following is my detail steps:

1.[Create an Active Directory application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application)

2.Get application id and authenication key and  Assign application to role.

3.Set the required permissions - select PowerBI

[image]

4.Download the [demo code](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/tree/master/samples/webforms/get-started-web-app-asp.net) from the github.

5.Add your clientSecret  and clientId in the Webconfig file

[image]

6.Change the Redirect URL in the default.aspx.cs and redirect.aspx.cs file that the same as  reply url in the registry AD WebApp

[image]

[image]

7.Publish the Website to the Azure and test it.

[image]